# How to implement custom Monad instance, especially for IObservable in FSharpPlus?

Tags: f#, system.reactive, monads, f#+

[FSharpPlus](https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpPlus/) provided [monad CE](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpPlus/abstraction-monad.html) and several monad transformers, and I want to use `ReaderT<'a, IObservable<'b>>` with FSharpPlus's `monad` CE, which requires a definition of monad instance of `IObservable`.

An example of desired code is

```
let test (x: IObservable<int>) = 
    monad {
        let! a = x
        let! b = x
        return a + b
    }
```

Which is expected to translate to

```
let test (v: IObservable<int>) = 
    x.SelectMany(fun n -> Observable.Return(n + 1))
```

But the monad CE does not support `IObservable` out of box, and adding extension like following to the same module of `test` function above does not work.

```
type IObservable<'a> with
    static member Return (x: 'T) : IObservable<'T> =
        Observable.Return(x)

    static member (>>=) (x: IObservable<'T>, f: 'T->IObservable<'U>) : IObservable<'U> = 
        x.SelectMany(f)
```

How to define monad instance for type `IObservable`?

---

**Update**

update use case from

```
let test (x: IObservable<int>) = 
    monad {
        let! n = x
        return n + 1
    }
```

to current one to prevent unintentional relation to Functor.

**Update**

As @Gus mentioned in the answer, it may not easy to direct add monad instance for IObservable.

After some search, since Functor instance of `IObservable` works (support `map` and `|>>`), it seems free monad may be one solution.

The following code seems worked:

```
open System
open System.Reactive.Linq
open FSharpPlus
open FSharpPlus.Data

let rec interpret (p: Free<IObservable<'a>, 'a>) : IObservable<'a> =
    match Free.run p with
    | Choice1Of2 x -> Observable.Return(x)
    | Choice2Of2 p' -> p'.SelectMany(interpret)

let test =
    monad {
        let! a = Free.liftF (Observable.Range(0, 4).Select(fun n -> n * 10))
        let! b = Free.liftF (Observable.Range(0, 10))
        return a + b
    }
    |> interpret
```

As a result, what we need to do is add `Free.liftF` before all bind in monad CE for `IObservable` s, and add a `interpret` helper function to the end.

The `interpret` implementation may not be stacksafe (or maybe it is by IObservable.SelectMany implementation?).

Although this compiles and seems run correctly for simple cases, I'm wondering is this usage of free monad correct?

Comment: I think the problem here is that extension members cannot provide operator overloads, such as `>>=`  (FS1215). I don't know any way around this, although there is a [suggestion](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/blob/main/RFCs/FS-1043-extension-members-for-operators-and-srtp-constraints.md) to allow it.

Comment: I suggest to post the question here: https://gitter.im/fsprojects/FSharpPlus

Comment: I believe the problem is `IObservable` is an interface. You need to extend an actual generic class

Comment: Also, Observables are better treated as functors and not as monads. `let test x = x |> Observable.map (fun n -> n + 1)`

Comment: @AMieres, thanks for your remind. The example was over simplified. I've modified the examples in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of writing this answer there is no way to have extension methods visible to trait constraints, although there is a [longstanding RFC](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/blob/main/RFCs/FS-1043-extension-members-for-operators-and-srtp-constraints.md) and PR in the F# compiler to implement it.

So, for the time being in order to add a type to an abstraction (like Monad) you need to either edit the type's source to add the required method or the abstraction source.

The former is basically impossible for `IObservable` I mean you can try submit them a PR, but the latter option is more feasible in the short term: submit a PR or at least open an issue in F#+ to add `IObservable` directly as Monad.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive explanation, after following materials provided by you, I've learnt it's not easy to direct add monad instance for IObservable. During this search, I've found free monad many be one light weight extension to IObservables, and with an interperter help function, we can embed IObservable into monad CE. But I don't know whether the usage and implementation of interpreter is correct. I've updated the question.

Comment: I can't comment on the Free Monad solution as I don't have so much experience using Free Monads without custom-made functors. Anyways, I wanted to point out that you can always create a wrapper type for IObservable and make it a monad. You'll have to wrap and unwrap, but you do that already in ReaderT so it might not be as bad.